# Perhaps joining 2 tables together when Users register

Tags: php, sql, database, select, join

So this is my sorta first time doing an Online RPG (MMORPG), It's a browser based-Pokemon game.

In the Database, l've created 2 tables;

1.Pokemons (Columns; ID#, PokemonName, PokemonType, Level, Exp, HPoints, ATT, DEF)
2.Users (Columns; ID, Full Name, E-Mail, Username, Password)

In the Register field, they put in their info (User, Pass, Email), then chooses a Starter Pokemon to fight with. My question is how would i interpret that into a SQL/PHP command that joins the starter pokemon to that User or vise versa?

Far as l know it's

SELECT * FROM table_name;

But let's say l wanted to choose THAT user who just registered. Would the * just automatically choose that player or will it select everything from the Users list (Currently 3 rows of users in the Table).

Im reading w3schools for the moment, but needed some real-time advice on how l should go about with this. Thanks again!

thepokemonrpg.x10.mx If you guys wanna see what l mean.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand you... What do you want? Select all users that have choosen a particular Pokemon class? Or just the user that just register in your application?

Answer (score 1):

This would indeed select *everything* from the `Users` table:

```
SELECT * FROM Users
```

The `*` doesn't mean all records, it just means all columns for any matching record.  However, since there's no filter, all records happen to be matching records.  If you want to only select a single record from that table, you would add a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='someusername'
```

There are a few different ways that you can construct the SQL query to include a value like that (since `someusername` would likely come from a variable and not be explicitly written like that).  Just be aware of [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) when building those queries.  You wouldn't want to accidentally publish a website where users can write their own database code and execute it on your server.

As for joining the tables, I currently don't see a way that you could do that.  These two tables define two distinct entities, but have no way to relate to one another.  There are a couple of ways you could do that, depending on how these entities are actually related.  To that end:

- Does a Pokemon always have exactly 0 or 1 owner? or;
- Does a Person always have exactly 0 or 1 Pokemon? or;
- Can a Pokemon have many owners and a Person have many Pokemons?

If the first statement is true, then you can add a `UserId` column to your `Pokemons` table and make it a [foreign key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) to the `Users` table.  That way every Pokemon record would indicate which User owns it.

If the second statement is true, then you can add a `PokemonId` column to your `Users` table and make it a foreign key to the `Pokemons` table.  That way every User record would indicate which Pokemon is currently owns.

If the third statement is true, then you'd need to add a joining table to maintain this many-to-many relationship.  Something like this:

```
PokemonUsers
------------
Id
PokemonId
UserId
```

Every record in this table would essentially be a link between a record in the `Users` table and a record in the `Pokemons` table.

Comment: @AnthonyAriBisnauth: Well, there's a difference between your authentication/authorization mechanism and your data access mechanism.  If, for example, your database code tends to be open to SQL injection vulnerabilities then the login form itself could be open to them.  While we're on the subject of security, I ***really*** hope that `Password` column doesn't contain a plain-text or 2-way-encrypted password.  It doesn't, right?  Because storing recoverable copies of user passwords is a *very* bad thing to do to one's users.

Comment: The passwords are safe to my understanding l was using an MD5 hash and heard lm not supposed to use that to stick with Salt for now so l've done just that. Upon Registering, a confirmation email gets sent by the Admin, the user clicks to confirms and thats it that's all l've setup. The RPG is still in the beginning phase, l havent done any work outside till where the User just signs up.

Comment: I see what you mean, to answer my previous question to the *SELECT* statement, couldn't l protect each page using PHP Sessions/Cookies while their logged to the RPG so each user is protected maybe opening sessions? for a second l thought it still might be possible to vulnerabilities, perhaps PHP Filtering?

Im going with the 3rd statement, Can a Pokemon have many owners and a Person have many Pokemons?

Comment: In turn yes, everyone will be able to have x amount of Pokemons per user so the quantity of Pokemons will infact exceed numbers not in the 500's anytime soon. Im currently on a Webhosting server, so lm limited to only 2 Databases, l'll do exactly what you mentioned and go from there! Thanks for your help David.